# Как на Reacte реализовать меню?

Tags: компоненты, react-hook

Расскажите(можно подробно) как на реакте реализовать меню?
Есть три ссылки. В зависимости от того какая ссылка активна нужно отрендерить в спец.блоке (#content) соответствующий этой ссылке контент

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting